# Cannot keep current user settings from updates - WPF .NET6 MSIX

Tags: c#, wpf, settings, .net-6.0, msix

I have an application using WPF .NET6 and packaging with MSIX. The application is deployed at a network share drive.

There are default settings build in the application but user will save individual user settings. I am trying to keep the user settings for each software update.

I find some similar questions for WPF clickonce application, but none of the solutions seems working for me. The user settings are overwritten with default settings on every software updates.

[Keep user's settings after altering assembly/file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924183/keep-users-settings-after-altering-assembly-file-version)

[Settings.Default.Upgrade() does not keep current settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219607/settings-default-upgrade-does-not-keep-current-settings)

For example, I added thoes lines to app() on start up. But it does not work.

```
// Copy user settings from previous application version if necessary
if (MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateSettings)
{
    MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateSettings = false;
    MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

So with MSIX package, how to keep the current user settings on each software update?

Comment: You could serialise your values to a fixed folder in localappdata rather than using the settings mechanism.

Comment: Yes. This could be my last option if there is no better solution.

Comment: I would say appdata should be your first option, rather than your last. App data. Settings is data. And it's for your app. Clue is there in the name.

Comment: Did you maybe find any solution for your problem? I am just rewriting .net framework wpf app to .net 6 and changing from clickonce to msix and I am stuck on figuring this problem out

Comment: No. Haven't find any better solution. Currently I am saving the user settings to a local file in a fixed folder. If there is no local file, app loads the build-in property settings.

Comment: Actually managed to find solution, see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219607/settings-default-upgrade-does-not-keep-current-settings)